# Does a DNA sequence has its own derivation tree or pattern?

Tags: bioinformatics

I am new to bioinformatics and natural language processing. In linguistics, they have Treebank - derivation/parse tree for each sentence. For example, a sentence "Sara sleeps" can be visualized by a tree: Sentence -> Subject Verb, Subject -> Sara, Verb -> sleeps.

I've heard about Genbank, a database for nucleotide sequences. Does a DNA has its own derivation tree, or is any pattern in a DNA sequence already known with current technology? I only heard about repeats.

Comment: Hello kate, I don't understand your question. The "derivation tree" you are describing is a structure which is specific to linguistics. How could a DNA have such a thing? It does not represent human language.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I think DNA has its own "language" which is probably unknown yet. My question is,(1) is the "language" of DNA already known? (2) is there any hint already known for understanding the "language" of DNA? Hint might be anything, such as patterns.. because I don't really understand much about bioinformatics.

Comment: DNA does not have its own language, it's a simple storage medium. It encodes information, but not in any way similar to a human language. Maybe this encoding fulfils the definition of a formal language, but if you have never gone into that branch of maths, any comparison will be more confusing than enlightening.

Comment: So better to think it as a storage medium.. Thank you very much!

Comment: The [Gene Ontology Consortium](http://geneontology.org/) might be of interest to you.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable information. So to understand the "language" of DNA, or at least to understand how DNA sequences are derived, simply parsing the nucleotides/DNA sequences is not enough because they are mere storage? To cover protein etc is too big for me for now, but it is interesting.

Comment: @kate I still don't understand your question. What are DNA sequences supposed to be derived from?

Comment: By "derive" I mean as in "derivation" or "derivation tree" in formal languages field.

Comment: I think protein (not DNA) domains might be something close to what you are looking for https://www.ebi.ac.uk/training/online/course/introduction-protein-classification-ebi/protein-classification/what-are-protein-domains

Comment: Thank you very much for your all warm and informative comments. I thought that studying DNA sequences only is enough but it seems that's not the case; it's much more complex than the languages that human made by themselves. Hope I can catch up on proteins and gene ontology, at least grasp the basic understanding. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example I guess that by "deriving" you mean something like decomposing into elements with diverse functions. Maybe we could apply this concept to DNA sequences: Some parts code proteins, which are decomposed into triplets, each of which codes an amino-acid. Other parts have regulatory functions: They can be motifs not coding a protein, but instead allowing a protein or something else to bind and modify the expression of nearby protein-coding parts. Other parts may contribute to the physical structure of the chromosome, or may have no function at all.

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. Thank you very much for your answer! Do all these - e.g. where is the part in a DNA sequence that involve in  function x - already known?

Comment: There are regulatory motif databases, and prediction algorithms for functions in a sequence, but all this is not fully known. Indeed, things are rarely fully regular in biology, so every bioinformatics predictions ideally should be completed with experimental confirmation. Also, the same sequence can sometimes be parsed in various way: a single DNA sequence may encode several proteins, depending on which portions are actually translated into amino-acids.
Some keywords you may be interested in: start codon, stop codon, open reading frame, 3'UTR, 5'UTR, binding box.